# why would I return a named function (object) from a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, object

Maybe I'm missing something obvious ... I've just started working with **JavaScript**, and when looking through an article about unit testing JavaScript with Jasmine, I came across this code:

```
function Convert(number, fromUnit) {  
    var conversions = {  
            distance : {  
                meters : 1,  
                cm     : 0.01,  
                feet   : 0.3048,  
                inches : 0.0254,  
                yards  : 0.9144  
            },  
            volume : {  
                litres : 1,  
                gallons: 3.785411784,  
                cups   : 0.236588236   
            }  
        },  
        betweenUnit = false,  
        type, unit;  

    for (type in conversions) {  
        if (conversions[type]) {  
            if ( (unit = conversions[type][fromUnit]) ) {  
                betweenUnit = number * unit * 1000;  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    return {  
        to : function (toUnit) {  
            if (betweenUnit) {  
                for (type in conversions) {  
                    if (conversions.hasOwnProperty(type)) {  
                        if ( (unit = conversions[type][toUnit]) ) {  
                            return fix(betweenUnit / (unit * 1000));  
                        }  
                    }  
                }  
                throw new Error("unrecognized to-unit");  
            } else {  
                throw new Error("unrecognized from-unit");  
            }    

            function fix (num) {  
                return parseFloat( num.toFixed(2) );  
            }  
        }  
    };  
}
```

It puzzled me as to why/how it is used, and what's the reason for it. It **appears** to return an object, which is a labeled function (method really, according to JavaScript naming convention), which wouldn't be called or returned upon creation.

After pondering about this and running it in chrome dev tools, it hit me that being called `Convert` with a capital `C`, it might be used as a constructor that would be used with `new` (again, according to JavaScript naming convention) so I might create an object like:
 `var tenFeet = new Convert(10, 'feet');`  and then use it as `tenFeet.to('cm');`.

This still makes no sense, since I wouldn't call the object (read: class) `Convert`, since it's not converting. I'd call the `to` method `convertTo`, and probably name `Convert` to `Measurement` or something.

1. Is this simply bad code with bad naming, am I simply rooted too deeply in conventional OO and "formal" languages, or am I missing something basic?
2. When / where / why would I use something like the above: "return labeled method" from an object in JavaScript?
3. Couldn't the same be achieved by enhancing the prototype of `Convert` with the same method?

Cheers, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is following the "read like a sentence" paradigm that some people like:

```
Convert(10, 'meters').to('feet') === 32.81
// Convert 10 meters to feet
```

You're right, the function goes against common naming conventions, but you can sort of guess that it shouldn't be created with the `new` keyword because there are no references to `this` in the function body.

This problem could've been avoided with proper documentation.

Comment: You ser, have the gist of it. Once you said "chaining", a quick look on google got me on my feet. You actually do the same in C# when using linq, but I guess it is abstracted away so it wasn't as obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Blender answered this correctly, but just in case other people stumble upon page, here's a little more info on what's happening.

Coming from more "formal" languages, I guess I was having issues with the "label" appearance of the `to` in the return statement.

from [MDN on **Label**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label):

> **Summary**
> Provides a statement with an identifier that you can refer to using a break or continue statement.
>
> For example, you can use a label to identify a loop, and then use the break or continue statements to indicate whether a program should interrupt the loop or continue its execution.
>
> **Syntax**
> label :  statement

Do notice that if you're creating an object, the syntax is similar. For example:

> person={firstname:"John",lastname:"Doe",age:50,eyecolor:"blue"};

This will result in an object looking like:

> object {firstname: "John", lastname: "Doe", age: 50, eyecolor: "blue"}

Another note is that if you're creating an array, you'll just use the commas, like this:

```
person=["John","Doe",50,"blue"];
```

This will give an array looking like:

```
["John", "Doe", 50, "blue"]
```

It takes a bit of time to get used to JavaScript syntax and logic, but all that really happens in my example is that the function returns an object, that has a method (named `to`) defined on it.
Once you have that object, you can call the method on it using the usual dot notation, which results in the `chaining` that is used in the above case. Or reusing **Blender's** example:

```
Convert(10, 'meters').to('feet') === 32.81`
```

Comment: The label syntax has nothing to do with this. JavaScript (sadly) doesn't distinguish data types when they are keys in objects, so `{to: 2}` and `{'to': 2}` are exactly the same. That function just returns an object, whose `to` property can be accessed with `.to` and the returned function can then be called.